# 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'to_string_rgb'

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm currently working through Sentdex's 'Django Part 15: Generating Django Charts and Graphs on your Website!', and having trouble using canvas.tostring_rgb().  I want to simply have a basic matplotlib canvas displayed on my django site.
I am currently using a MacBook Pro, OS X 10.8.5.

```
graphIMG = PIL.Image.fromstring("RGB",canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.to_string_rgb())
```

Is this something similar to switching backend of matplotlib to matplotlib.use('TkAgg')?

Thanks in advance for the help.